# Is there a way to predict if exp is going to return inf

Tags: python, numpy

This is the code:

```
m=0
x=3090531.63
m=m+np.exp(x)
print(m)
```

output:

```
inf
```

I know that the result cant be produced by float but it is important that this number is used

Answer (score 0):

You can use [numpy.isinf](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isinf.html) function.

```
import numpy as np
np.isinf(np.exp(x))
```

which will return `True` if the result is infinity and `False` if not.

Answer (score 0):

You can typecast it to `str`. Then you it.

```
m=0
x=3090531.63
m=m+np.exp(x)
print(m)
m=str(m)
print(m)
```

OUTPUT :

```
inf
'inf'
```

Now you can use it however you want for example

```
if m == 'inf':
     pass      #It can be anything according to your code like break, True etc.
```

You use `math` library.

```
math.isinf(x) #Returns True if inf else False
```

Or use :

```
m == float('inf') # will be true if m is inf
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an approximation - but will give you some idea:

```py
import sys
x=sys.float_info.max
print(x)
#1.7976931348623157e+308
import numpy as np
print(np.log(x)/np.log(np.e))#ln
#709.782712893384
x=1.7976931348623159e+308
print(x)
#inf
print(np.log(x)/np.log(np.e))#ln
#inf
```

And it kind of matches the real life:

```py
print(no.exp(709))
8.218407461554972e+307
print(np.exp(710))
/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/temp_iiec_codefile.py:11: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  print(np.exp(710))
inf
```

So the answer would be max non-inf result you will get for `x` somewhere between `709` and `710`